# how to solve this "Please choose product options by visiting" variant product woocommerce error?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, variant

[image]

how to solve this "Please choose product options by visiting" variant product woocommerce error?

Comment: Contact theme dev.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem today. But while reading through a similar issue on [WordPress Support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-please-choose-product-options-by-visiting/), I discovered that it's related to a plugin that blocks rendering of the product page until its JS or CSS files are loaded. In my case it was

> Yoast SEO: WooCommerce

To fix, you need to identify the plugin and disable it:

1. Disable all your plugins except WooCommerce and maybe your page
   builder.
2. Check if the issue persist - usually it will go away.
3. Start enabling your most essential plugins one at a time.
4. Check for the problem every time you enable one of your plugins.
5. Once you have found your vilain, you can try to remove any ***Defer Render-blocking JavaScript*** or contact the plugin developer for solution if you must use the plugin.

Since ***Yoast SEO: WooCommerce*** was not critical to my store, I simply disabled it and I've been happy :)